# Servlet recuperar Objeto

Tags: javascript, servlet

É possível uma servlet recuperar objeto populado no requestParameter?

Tipo vindo do Javascript?

```
req.getParameter("objeto");
```

Tenho o objeto Pessoa que possui

Nome

Telefone

no Javascript eu enviar

```
var obj = {nome: 'Carlos', telefone: '929999999'}
```

Como recuperar esse objeto populado no Servlet invés de String

```
Obj obj = req.getParameter("obj");
```

Comment: Poderia melhorar sua pergunta?
Não da pra entender o que você deseja atingir.

Comment: Sim, com certeza

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com sua descrição, você deve estar enviando esse objeto via `AJAX`.

```
var obj = {nome: 'Carlos', telefone: '929999999'}
$.ajax("url", {
  data: obj,
  method: "POST"
  success:function(data){
          console.log(data);
  }
}
```

Em sua servlet, basta pegar esse objeto através do método `getParameter()` disponível no objeto `HttpServletRequest`.

Ficaria algo assim

```
doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
  String telefone = request.getParameter("telefone");

  response.getWriter().write("Nome submetido foi: " + nome + "\n Telefone submetido foi: " + telefone);
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Qualquer dúvida poste nos comentários.

Comment: o request.getParameter(), sempre receberá String então, né?

Comment: Sempre. Se você quiser enviar outro tipo de dados, deve ir mais a fundo e pesquisar sobre Part, MultiPart etc.